# How would i Add a Twig Function

Tags: twig

How would I add this as a function using twig.

```
<?php quadmenu(array("theme_location" => "main", "theme" => "default_theme")); ?>
```

Only point of reference I found was

**Make functions available in Twig**

If you have functions that you use a lot and want to improve readability of your code, you can make a function available in Twig by using Timber\Twig_Function inside the timber/twig hook.

```
/**
 * My custom Twig functionality.
 *
 * @param Twig_Environment $twig
 * @return $twig
 */
add_filter( 'timber/twig', function( \Twig_Environment $twig ) {
    $twig->addFunction( new Timber\Twig_Function( 'edit_post_link', 'edit_post_link' ) );
    return $twig;
} );
```

Answer (score 1):

As `quadmenu` appears to be a global function, you could just chain it

```
add_filter( 'timber/twig', function( \Twig_Environment $twig ) {
    $twig->addFunction( new Timber\Twig_Function( 'quadmenu', 'quadmenu' ) );
    return $twig;
} );
```

Then you could use it like the following inside `twig`

```
{{ quadmenu({ 'theme_location': 'main', 'theme' : 'default_theme', }) }}
```

---

*More possible ways on how to add custom functionality can be found [here](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/advanced.html#filters)*